# Type of object returned by listOf Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

As Kotlin documentation says `listOf<T>` has three implementations: for no arguments, one argument and varargs. Each function should return immutable `List<T>`.

```
val emptyList = listOf<String>()
val oneArgList = listOf("asd")
val varargsList = listOf("asd", "asd")

if (emptyList is MutableList) println("emptyList is mutable")
if (oneArgList is MutableList) println("oneArgList is mutable")
if (varargsList is MutableList) println("varargList is mutable")
```

Execution of code above results in

```
oneArgList is mutable
varargList is mutable
```

Why it works that way? Is this desired behaviour?

Comment: When you target the JVM, Kotlin probably uses the `ArrayList` under the hood, so that's why you get those results. As for the empty list, it returns the `EmptyList` instance that you can find under `kotlin.collections.Collections`

Comment: Another thing that seems interesting is if you cast the two non-empty lists to a `MutableList` the cast will succeed, but any modifications you attempt to make will throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. Casting the empty list will fail.

Comment: @Quinn that is because its `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` not `java.util.ArrayList`, they are very different.

Answer (score 5):

> Why it works that way?

If you check out the source code, you will find it actually creates a Java `ArrayList`. This leverages the JDK instead of having to implement an `ArrayList` in Kotlin. Note that your cast to `MutableList` is a bad coding practice even if it is successful since the `listOf()` function already specifies it is a `List` and not a `MutableList`.

`emptyList()` (or `listOf()`) on the other hand uses an `EmptyList` singleton implemented in Kotlin that is truly immutable.

> Is this desired behaviour?

Actually no. However it does the trick presenting an immutable interface instead. It doesn't really matter how exactly the backing data structure is implemented as long as it conforms to the interface contract. You as a programmer should also stick to the contract when using it.

Comment: Is there a proper way to check if a list is actually mutable then?

Comment: @Quinn Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @m0skit0 You didn't explain why there is a discrepance between the Kotlin docs and the actual result of the mutable check. How does it do the trick when the returned list is mutable while you are expecting it to be immutable?

Comment: @nulldroid I believe the returned list is in fact immutable, you will get a crash if you try to mutate it (even if you cast is to a `MutableList`). I think what he means by `presenting an immutable interface` is that the list returned will not have access to methods such as `.add` or `.remove` so it would be hard to try to mutate it.

Comment: oh ok, so just the check is going wrong? thanks for making that clear

Comment: Kotlin's `listOf` calls through to `arrayListOf`. The Kdoc for `listOf` lies. The list is very much mutable. It's only "immutable" if you don't cast it to a mutable one.

Comment: @Quinn On the contrary, the actual returned list is indeed mutable, it is a Java `ArrayList`. However the exposed interface for `listOf()` is `List` (immutable) which doesn't have mutation methods (add, remove, etc...), so you actually can't mutate it unless you cast it to `MutableList` (which would be weird, hence my comment of a bad coding practice).

Comment: @Tenfour04 It does not lie, the exposed interface is immutable. It is a black-boxed list, you don't need to know the implementation details.

Comment: @m0skit0 It seems that the returned list is not mutable, even if you do cast it to `MutableList` you still can not mutate it: https://pl.kotl.in/mrBKG6oRq

Comment: @m0skit0 So the source code lies? You're right, it throws an exception when I try to mutate one. Never tried it before.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The source code for `listOf` is `= arrayListOf`... EDIT: nevermind. I was looking at the Kotlin js source code, where it appears that `listOf` truly is mutable if casted.

Comment: @Tenfour04 And? It is black-boxed by the interface.

Comment: Yep. This code succeeds if you set the target to JS: https://pl.kotl.in/uL_KmjlaP

Comment: In JVM it uses `Arrays.asList()` which returns an immutable list.

Comment: Right. If you run this code, it succeeds when targeting JS and fails when using JVM: https://pl.kotl.in/iUDl04fmA

Comment: @Tenfour04 However you're just randomly casting lists, which is not the intended behavior and actually has no real usage.

Comment: You're right, I was just testing. The distinction between immutable and read-only is important. In fact, on JVM, it will succeed if you have more than one item in the original list. The Kdocs are actually correct. The `listOf` function with one argument says it's "immutable", and the one with multiple arguments says it's "read-only".

Answer (score 1):

You say "each one should return immutable lists", but if you look at the documentation for the three functions, the first one says it returns an immutable List, and the next two say they return a **read-only** List. A read-only List is not necessarily immutable.

The List interface does not guarantee immutability. It only describes itself as providing solely read-only methods.

In actual practice, haphazardly doing `is` checks is a big time code smell. There are some narrow use cases that kind of make sense. Like Google's [recommended way to create a DialogFragment and communicate back to the Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents), but stuff like this is (IMO) a hack to get around regrettable decisions from the original design of Activities and Fragments. In the case of this example, you would control the definition of your interface, and all implementations of it, so its a little harder for things to go wrong.

Comment: Another factor is that even if `listOf()` happens to return a mutable implementation in some cases _now_, there's no guarantee it will continue to do so in future.  One of the benefits of having defined it to return a high-level interface like `List` is that future versions can return other things for better performance, immutability, or other improvements.  So you really shouldn't make any assumptions based on the current implementation.

Comment: @gidds Exactly, this is what I was referring to as black-boxing, or hiding the implementation details through the interface.